# Can Visual Studio Community install TFS (Team Foundation Server)?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013

Our team decide to use Visual Studio Community instead of Visual Studio 2013. I wonder can we install TFS in Visual Studio Community and work well? Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic and should be directed at the tool vendor's sales or support services

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Visual Studio Community edition is feature equal to Visual Studio Professional except that in an organization it can only be used for open source projects, academic research or learning. For other commercial scenarios you're only allowed to use the Community edition up to 5 users.

Team Foundation Server is a separate product. If you have an MSDN subscription (which you won't have if you're using VS Community), you get licenses to install TFS.

However, instead of installing TFS you can also look at [Visual Studio Team Services](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/what-is-visual-studio-online-vs), a hosted version of TFS which is free up to five users.

So, if you're with less than 5 users, you can use Community and Visual Studio Team Services completely free.

Comment: There is a free TFS Express for up to 5 users. Can the community edition connect to that? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46922

Comment: @Simon_Weaver I would assume that's possible. Haven't tried it however.

Comment: On the feature comparison chart it shows zero features for TFS for community edition. Will update later when my corrupted TFS upgrade gets fixed :-/

Comment: I just tested and confirmed that VS Community edition 2015 can connect to on-premise TFS 2015 Express edition.

Comment: And for ***Visual Studio 2017 Community*** ?

Comment: @PreguntonCojoneroCabrón It's the same for Visual Studio 2017 Community. Or did you mean something else?